# Set thousands separator in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, formatting

I am making an MVC5 app using Razor.

I set the NumberFormat in my Current Culture like this:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ";";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Then I put some property typed double in one of my views with the value 1800.01

```
@MyDecimalValue
```

And what I get is `1800;01`. What I would like to get is `1 800;01`. In order to include all the parameters I have set, I have to use something like this:

```
@MyDecimalValue.ToString("N")
```

I think that when Razor's engine turns my Razor code into HTML, it calls the ToString() method, which ignores the thousands separator I have set.

Is there any way to make Razor to render the thousands separator without calling ToStringMethod(string format) ?

Any help you can provide will be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, Razor will call [`Decimal.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses the ["G" general format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString).

This format doesn't include thousands separators, from the msdn:

> Result: The most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation.
>   Uses the
>   [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   properties
>   [`NegativeSign`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign(v=vs.110).aspx),
>   [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   and
>   [`PositiveSign`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positivesign(v=vs.110).aspx)

As far as I know it is not possible to replace the standard numeric formats in the same way [you can replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940403/change-default-datetime-format-for-razor) the whole datetime `ShortDatePattern` and `LongDatePattern`. All you can do is replace the `NumberFormatInfo` properties mentioned above like `NegativeSign`.

However you still have alternatives in Razor, like adding a `DisplayFormat` attribute to the property in your model or creating a **Display Template** for Decimals. See the answer from Darin in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067375/html-displayfor-decimal-format).